# how to check that at least one check box should be selected out of group of checkbox on click of one another checkbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

I have a form and in which there are some groups of check boxes. Please find the below code.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"  />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1-4-2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.keyfilter-   1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function (){
        $("#mainfruit").click(function(){
            if($('#mainfruit').is(':checked')){
                $('input[id^="fruit_"]').attr ( "checked" , false );                
                $('input[id^="fruit_"]').attr ( "disabled" , false );
            }else{
                $('input[id^="fruit_"]').attr ( "checked" , false );                
                $('input[id^="fruit_"]').attr ( "disabled" , true );                
            }
        });
        $("#idchecktest").validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true
                      },
                fruit: {
                    subselect: true
                      }
                },
            messages: {
                foldername: {
                        required: "<br>Please enter the name."
                    },
                fruit: {
                        subselect:"<br>Please select sub checkbox."
                      }
              },
            //errorClass: 'errortext',
            errorLabelContainer: "#messagebox"
        });
    });
$.validator.addMethod('subselect', function (value) { 
    if($('#mainfruit').is(':checked')){
        /*var che=$('input[id^="fruit_"]');
        var i=0;
        che.each(function (i){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                i=1;
                return true;
                //break;
            }else{
                i=0;
                //continue;
            }
        });*/
        if($("'input[id^="fruit_"]':checked").length>0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}, 'check atleast one checkbox');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="checktest" action="" id="idchecktest" method="get">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Select Fruits </td>
    <td><p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" id="mainfruit" />
      Fruits<br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="mango" id="fruit_mango" disabled="disabled" />
        Mango <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="pineapple" id="fruit_pineapple" disabled="disabled"/>
        Pineapple<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="watermellon" id="fruit_watermellon" disabled="disabled"/>
        watermellon        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="orange" id="fruit_orange" disabled="disabled"/>
Orange</p>      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><div id="messagebox"> </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here in above code I have used jquery form validation plugin. Now I want to add a custom validation for group of checkboxes i.e. whenever user checks the Fruits checkbox he must have to select at least one check box under it. If he checks only fruits checkbox and not the check box below it Then an errors message should be get displayed.

In above code its shows an errors message related to checkboxes but the respective error message not gose when we uncheck the maincheckbox i.e. the fruits check box.
1. Please tell me friends what is wrong in my jquery code.
2. I also want to know that is it possible to user same custom validation function for another group of check boxes like Flowers

Please guide me in this friends.
Thank You!

Comment: if `$(elements).prop('checked')` returns true, at least one checkbox in the colletion of elements have been checked.

Comment: @adeneo Hi! Here in above code I what that when I clicke the fruit checkbox then rest of the four subcheckbox should get enabled and user must select at least one check box out of above four. If he dont select the check boxes out of those four sub checkboxes then an error message should be displayed dynamically on fly and that message should get invisible as soon as user clicks at least one check box out of the four sub checkboxes.

Comment: `checked` and `disabled` are properties, not attributes, so in jQuery you must use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: Within `if($('#mainfruit').is(':checked')){`, your conditional logic is faulty.  You are setting `checked` to `false` under both conditions.